# Angular2 загрузка стилей

Tags: angular2

У меня есть компонент у которого возможно две темы и соответственно 2 различных `css`. Можно ли как-то изменять содержание `styleUrls` либо `styles` без перезагрузки страницы? Пробовал забивать в `localStorage` переменную с тем какая у меня будет тема и потом при загрузке компонента ставить определенную тему, но для этого нужна перезагрузка страницы.

Вот то что у меня получилось:

```
var theme = localStorage.getItem('color'); 
if(theme == "dark") 
 var color = require('../constructor/dark.bootstrap.min.css'); 
else 
 var color = require('../constructor/bootstrap.min.css'); 
var styles = require('./constructor_area.component.css'); 
@Component({ 
 selector: 'constructor-area', 
 templateUrl: './constructor_area.component.html', 
 styles: [styles, color] 
})
```

Comment: можно, средствами css, лучше всего эта задача решается через препроцессоры less или sass: `.dark { // все нужные стили } .light {// все нужные стили}` и в зависимости от темы добавляете нужный класс к body

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавлять класс с название темы например к тегу `html`, а оба-двое файлов стилей построить в соответствии с этим. Т.е. примерно так:

default.theme.css

```
bg {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

dark.theme.css

```
html.dark bg {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #ff0;
}
```

*.html

```
<html>
....

<div class="bg">
  zsdfsadfsdf
</div>
```

по умолчанию - дефолтная тема, добавил класс `dark` к `html` - тёмная...
Если использовать sass/less/stylus то будет наверно не слишком замороченно.

PS. возможно потребуется отключить инкапсуляцию дома в компоненте. `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`

PPS. разумеется цсс должны грузиться оба сразу чтобы переключаться